# Sort and filter Javascript library

Tags: gratis, library, javascript, web-development

I'm looking for a JS library (or libraries if sort and filter functionnalities are separated) which allow me to sort and filter an HTML table.

My main need is to get a library quickly operational for basic sorting and filtering (alphabetics and numerical).

Requirements:

- Must works on Firefox 17 and above
- Very few customization (I should just give my table's id to the lib, no heavy html changes needed)
- Ability to combine some filters
- Not buggy if I dynamically add a new row in my table.

Comment: I have to ask: Why Firefox 17? I'm familiar with organizations getting stuck on older versions of IE but this is the first I've heard of someone needing an old version of Firefox. Your site just get a lot of visitors on that version?

Comment: @BSMP Yes an important part of my end users are on that version. I already suggest them to update. I don't think it is a huge problem, gap between Firefox version is not as problematic as IE one's.

Answer (score 1):

[ListJs](http://www.listjs.com/overview) is an option. You dont need to change your html much, but I'd think you have to do some javascript to make it work like you desire.